# cifar10: TypeError: range() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

When I build the file: [`cifar10_train.py`](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py), it occurs that:

```
  ...
  File ".../cifar10.py", line 271, in loss
    indices = tf.reshape(tf.range(FLAGS.batch_size), [FLAGS.batch_size, 1])
TypeError: range() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The trouble occurs in the file [`cifar10.py`](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using TensorFlow version 0.5 and a more recent version of the `cifar10_train.py` script. The signature of `tf.range()` was changed to accept a single argument (like the Python `range()` built-in function) after version 0.5 was released.

I'd always recommend [upgrading to the latest version](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html) of TensorFlow, since the runtime has had many performance and stability improvements since the initial release.

If that doesn't work, the following equivalent code is taken [from the original release](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f41959ccb2d9d4c722fe8fc3351401d53bcf4900/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py#L364):

```
indices = tf.reshape(tf.range(0, FLAGS.batch_size, 1), [FLAGS.batch_size, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I alter the command as follows:

```
#indices = tf.reshape(tf.range(FLAGS.batch_size), [FLAGS.batch_size, 1])
indices = tf.reshape(range(FLAGS.batch_size), [FLAGS.batch_size, 1])
```

Then, the code works well.